# Decimal field is transformed to string using createQueryBuilder

Tags: typeorm

This is my table:

```
@Entity('products')
export class Products {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    @IsNumber()
    public id: number;

    @Column('decimal', { 
      precision: 20,
      scale: 2,
      transformer : { 
        to (value)  {
          return value ; 
        }, 
        from (value)  { 
          return parseFloat (value) ; 
        }, 
      }, 
    })
    @IsNotEmpty()
    price: number;
}
```

In my ormconfig file I have:

```
...
bigNumberStrings: false,
supportBigNumbers: true,
```

If I do:

```
return await this.repository.find();
```

Everything works correctly. The price field returns it as a decimal.

But if I use createQueryBuilder it brings it back as a string:

```
 return await this.repository.createQueryBuilder("products")
    .select([
      'products.id AS id',
      'products.price AS price'])  
    .getRawMany();
```

Please, could someone tell me how I can fix it?

Comment: Can someone help me?